# Which MySQL data type is good for storing autocomplete terms?

Tags: mysql

I am developing an app in cakephp with user auth. Users will add their customer names every time they get orders. So I want to have an auto complete textfield for customer name to add orders. Each user will have their own set of customer names.

- So should i create a big text to store customer names(all terms with comma seperated)

  / or /
- varchar for each term (1 term in 1 record)?

I will use foreign key to separate users customers.

I am planning to use jQuery ui auto complete with sourcing terms from the customer table values.

My big concern is database capacity, I would like to save the space in database because I have other tables and a lot of users too.

(I do not have a programming background, so please forgive me for my typo)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple records, one for each term.  That is what databases are designed to store.

If you store all the terms in a comma separated list, you will discover that there are lots of things that you cannot easily do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. I saw wordpress tables, wp_options are stored in a "longtext" data type. That is why I thought I can use the same method. But as you said I am going to use 1 to 1 method. I feel your method is easy